# Proper Storing of DataURIs in a Variable

Tags: php, variables, data-url

There is probably a much more elegant way to say the title, but that's the best I could come up with because frankly I am feeling silly that I don't know the answer and even have to ask but that's how you learn, so no shame necessary.

I have stored dataURIs such as :

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

in a variable by simply doing: `$some_var = "INSERT_ABOVE";` and has usually worked fine, but I am finding in a piece of code I am working on right now that the code breaks anytime one of the variable=>datauri scheme I showed above is used but deleting that line, fixes the code.

So I am not sure ?WHY? this particular datauri is breaking the code and shouldn't anything inside `"" QUOTATIONS` be treated as a literal string? Is there a best practice or should I say recommended way of storing datauris as variables to be used through the code, so it doesn't break?

Any thoughts and/or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, TIA.

PS. This wasn't just due to the backslash at the end, it was also that the string by itself wasn't being respected, now it is storing into variable like this, thanks. Since the title most accurately describes what was being achieved, I think its more appropriate.

Comment: Because it ends with a backslash - it escapes your ending quote.

Comment: @Eihwaz, yes I did consider that myself but any attempt that I can think of to mitigate that would alter the datauri's content? no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  [Heredoc string quoting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). It's another way to represent strings in PHP. It can eliminate your problem of ending quote getting escaped by string data.

```
  $str = <<<EOD
        data:image/png;base64,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\

  EOD;

  echo $str;
```

Comment: AHA +1, what a novel idea, I can't believe I didn't think of that given that I use Heredoc quite often (especially recently) so I can't believe that didn't click, you are awesome, thank you very much. Once I confirm that it works stable, then I will come back and mark the answer. Thanks again.